# display:inline-block in <p> and <div>

Tags: css

I put a div with `display:inline-block` inside a `<p></p>`. The div clears the left. But if I put it in a `<div></div>`, it follows the flow.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jDBxN/

Anyone know why? How to make `<p>` with `inline-block` behaves the same as `<div>`?

Browser is Chrome 29

Comment: Same effect in Firefox. Switching to `<span>` solves the problem though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid, you cannot nest a block level element inside `p` tag, consider using `span` instead

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jDBxN/1/)

If you want, you can also nest a `p` tag inside `div` but the text will lose it's meaning, so better use `p` and nest `span` inside `p`.

From the Spec: [Resource](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

Comment: The whole point of using `display:inline-block` is that it isn't a block level element any more, so I guess the OP thought it would be okay. (btw, you might want to include a link to the spec where it says it's invalid; always good to back up your assertions :-)).

Comment: @Spudley was just searching for the link and thanks for the suggestion ... :)